# Javascript Checkbox add value Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a code like these:

```js
var fails = 'fail';
var sucs = 'success';

function showResult(state){
 if(state){
      document.getElementById("hasil").value=sucs;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("hasil").value=fails;
    }         
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <th>TARGET</th>
      <th>RESULT</th>
      <th>NOTES</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='target' onclick='showResult(this.checked);' /></td>
      <td><textarea name='result[]' id='hasil'>fail</textarea></td>       <td><textarea name='notes[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='target' onclick='showResult(this.checked);' /></td>
      <td><textarea name='result[]' id='hasil'>fail</textarea></td>       <td><textarea name='notes[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='target' onclick='showResult(this.checked);' /></td>
      <td><textarea name='result[]' id='hasil'>fail</textarea></td>       <td><textarea name='notes[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

I want to create that checkbox, if it's clicked, it will change textarea on that row to `success`. If I uncheck, it will change back to `fail`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not name, getElementsByClassName returns a collection....

Comment: I try to change it with ID but it only works for the first row...

Comment: Because ids are singular. Hopefully someone can show you how to get the reference to the checkbox. Select the parent tr, find the text area and set the value. I can not code that on my phone.

Comment: I will try find way to do that... thanks before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only works for the first row.

As @epascarello said, because `ids` are singular. so you need to select the parent `tr`, find the text area and set the value.

You can do in this way.

```js
$('[type=checkbox]').change(function() {

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
    $row.find('textarea[name="result[]"]').text("sucess");
  } else {
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
    $row.find('textarea[name="result[]"]').text("fail");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <th>TARGET</th>
      <th>RESULT</th>
      <th>NOTES</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='target' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name='result[]' id='hasil'>fail</textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name='notes[]' class='form-control'></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='target' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name='result[]' id='hasil'>fail</textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name='notes[]' class='form-control'></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='target' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name='result[]' id='hasil'>fail</textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name='notes[]' class='form-control'></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: hello, it works smooth in snippet, but not in my code. Is it need to be placed on head or body? or it's not matter?

Comment: Could you tell me on which technology you are working with? and as of now considered HTML, so you can put this in header tag. in `$(document).ready(function(){yourcode});`

Comment: I'm very sorry... I missed bracket after function.... It works perfectly now.. thank you so much!